# Why am I having less options in Palette in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio (Bumblebee - 2021.1.1). Unlike other YouTubers having many options in Palette, I am having only a few options. Do I need to download any other libraries? If so from where should I download them? [Screenshot of my Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUoC6.png)

Comment: You are editing a _menu_ XML. Edit one of the _layout_ files and you'll see much more elements (assuming that you're talking about the missing things, like TextView, Button etc.).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.